# Trying to change DataContext of main window from usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, datacontext

On initialization of main window i set DataContext to usercontrol and on this usercontrol i have an event which suppose to change datacontext of main window to another usercontrol but nothing happens.

Here is xaml for main window:

```
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" Width="auto" Height="auto" />
</Grid>
```

Here is C# for main window:

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new LogInViewModel();
    }
```

Here is xaml for LogInUserControl:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="250">
            <StackPanel Width="125">
                <TextBlock Text="Email:" Margin="5,0,5,0" Width="auto"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Width="125">
                <TextBlock Text="Password:" Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="auto"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBox Margin="5,0,5,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <PasswordBox Margin="0,0,0,5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="23" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <Button Content="Log In" Margin="0,0,0,5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock Text="don't have account yet ?" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="5"/>
        <TextBlock Name="TBSignUp" Text="Sign Up" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="5" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="TextBlock_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="TextBlock_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp" Foreground="#FF0B36F5"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

and here is C# for LogInUserControl:

```
public partial class LogInView : UserControl
{
    string BlackForeground = "#FF000000" ;
    string OriginalForeground = "#FF0B36F5";
    public LogInView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void TextBlock_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        TBSignUp.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(OriginalForeground));
        DataContext = new RegisterView();
    }

    private void TextBlock_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        TBSignUp.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(BlackForeground));
    }
}
```

Comment: Both "*change DataContext of main window **from** usercontrol*" and "*change datacontext of main window **to** another usercontrol*" sounds horrible. Don't even think about it.

Comment: do you have any other idea how to change views in wpf ? and can you explain why it sounds horrible ?

Comment: Change views for example by assigning a value to the Content property of a ContentControl. A DataTemplate with an appropriate DataType would be chosen automatically, and the DataContext of the elements in the DataTemplate (e.g. a UserControl) would be set to the current Content. Start here: [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview). Or take a look at Page Navigation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WPF you can get a shell (first) window from anywhere:

```
System.Windows.Window shell = System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow;
```

OR

```
 Application.Current.Windows[0];
```

but I recommend passing the reference if needed.

look at the [MVVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel) pattern, you need to implement property change notification in your view model class to bind properties.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what i was looking for :)

Comment: I love you, this saved me so much time. I couldn't find this anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set it on `App.xaml.cs`.

**App.xaml.cs:**

```
public class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
         MainWindow window=new MainWindow();
         LogInViewModel vm=new LogInViewModel(); // You need to set DataContext...
         window.DataContext=vm; // ...before showing up the window.
         window.Show();
    }
 }
```

In the ViewModel patterns that I found from research, usage is before `DataContext`, after `Show();`.

I hope that solves your problem.